# Python responses module is erratic with multi-threading in Linux

Tags: python-requests, python-multithreading, python-responses

I am trying to use the *responses* module to mock an HTTP server and I have the feeling it is broken when calls requests are multi-threaded.

Consider the following:

```
import json
import responses
import requests
import threading

try:
   import urlparse
except ModuleNotFoundError:
   import urllib.parse as urlparse


server_url = 'http://server'
headers_json = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

def init():

    def endpoint(request):
        id = urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(request.path_url).query)["id"][0]
        data = {"foo": int(id)}
        return 200, headers_json, json.dumps(data)

    responses.add_callback(
        responses.GET, server_url + '/',
        callback=endpoint,
    )

@responses.activate
def test():

    init()

    def responses_routine():
        resp = requests.get(
            server_url + '/?id=456',
            headers=headers_json,
        )

        # {"foo": "456"}
        print(resp.json()["foo"])

    def print_routine():
        print("456")

    # This will print "456"
    #responses_routine()

    # This will print "456" after 2 seconds
    #threading.Timer(2, print_routine).start()

    # This will fail
    threading.Timer(2, responses_routine).start()

test()
```

It fails with a stack that clearly indicates that no call to *responses* was made. The *requests* module **did** try to make an HTTP code to a remote server.

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/python3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/opt/python/python3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 57, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/opt/python/python3.6.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/python3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/opt/python/python3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/opt/python/python3.6.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/python/python3.6.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/python/python3.6.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/python/python3.6.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/opt/python/python3.6.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/opt/python/python3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 181, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/opt/python/python3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x2aaab0930438>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/python3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/opt/python/python3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/opt/python/python3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='server', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /?id=456 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x2aaab0930438>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/python3.6.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/python/python3.6.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 1182, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "tmp.py", line 35, in responses_routine
    headers=headers_json,
  File "/opt/python/python3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 116, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/python3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/python3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/python3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/python3.6.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='server', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /?id=456 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x2aaab0930438>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

It fails on Redhat 6.6. I am using Python 3.6.6 (it also fails in 2.7 with a similar stack) with requests 2.22 and responses 0.10.6.

It's like when the main thread exited, all "handles" to *responses* were lost...
Any clues ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what's created within the context manager *responses.activate* should not escape it.
In the code above, the underlying thread of the Timer object would be joined outside the scope, hence potentially run outside the context manager scope, which yield the exception.